# Norse god/goddess of law or justice

Tags: norse, goddesses

Is there a Norse god/goddess of law or justice? Or is law/justice a too western of concept to have back then?

Comment: Law and Justice are two unrelated concepts.  That is why the Legislature and Judiciary are unconnected in Western democracies.  Or are you suggesting that they were combined by Norse myth?

Comment: The concepts Law and Justice are pretty darn closely related. Are you suggesting that the Judiciary has nothing to do with law? It's stated purpose is to interpret and apply the law. It's full of *law*yers who went to *law* school, and work for *law* firms, representing clients in courts of *law*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes!

[**Tyr**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BDr) was a norse God of law and war. Evidence suggests that he was once head of the pantheon, but was supplanted by Odin and Thor. He was wise and brave, the only of the gods courageous enough to offer his hand as collateral when they wanted to bind Fenris.

**[Forseti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forseti)**, the son of Balder, is mentioned by Snorri as a good mediator and judge. His name also means "the presiding one", so he has been linked with law and justice by scholars.