# Did Sif (the Norse Goddess) ever become a Warrior in mythology?

Tags: norse, goddesses

In modern recreations of the character (e.g. in the Marvel Universe), Sif is depicted as a [Warrior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sif_(comics)), usually of Justice*), generally associated with the aspect(s) of Justice. However, in the original mythology, Sif was known as the [Goddess of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sif).

[This question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/norse-god-goddess-of-law-or-justice) covers that thee were actually 2 other gods/goddesses of law and justice already, so the idea that Sif should take on that aspect is a stretch.

Is there anything in the mythology that makes this connection between Sif and any Warrior archetypes?

---

<sup>*The Wiki does not state this, but her character is always the "voice of reason" among the other Norse warriors in the comics/movies)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

*wip*

Do know that as good as everything we know of Norse mythology comes from writers after the Christianization of Scandinavia so I can't write about any older myths (this might be my shortcoming since there are definitely users on this site with a much greater knowledge on this subject than myself).

**The only connection Sif would have to warrior culture would be her marriage to the storm god Thor.**

In a Dictionary of Northern Mythology the author noted that Sif's name was

> Her name seems to mean “relation by marriage,” so even here we find nothing of
> a personality or function – just a familial association.

> Sif’s association with
> the vegetation on the surface of the Earth, which is suggested by the nature of her
> hair, is also corroborated by the fact that a species of moss
> (Polytrichum aureum) was called haddr Sifjar (“Sif’s hair”) in Old
> Norse.

<sub>[Dictionary of Northern Mythology Rudolf Simek
D.S. Brewer, 1996](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Dictionary_of_Northern_Mythology.html?id=MZ24QgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)</sub>  <sub>quote taken from [Norse Mythology for Smart People: Sif](https://norse-mythology.org/sif/)</sub>

*personal opinion:*

*I think Sif's warrior like looks and behaviour in the movies is ofcourse greatly exaggerated in the name of entertainment. And rightly so since I enjoyed the extra take of her being a beautiful strong weapon wielding woman. But as most cinematic versions of any mythology or history they are mostly incorrect and use some "artistic liberties" to make the plot more available and titillating to a broader audience.*